# Who wrote this potion recipe?

Tags: word, cipher

Below is a recipe for a Fainting Draught written by a famous wizard. The potionmaster who created this recipe has hidden his name within the recipe. Can you find the name of this potion's author?

[image: recipe]

Comment: Is it another Harry Potter themed puzzle? :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor It is indeed. No knowledge of Harry Potter is required for solving this one though.

Comment: Is this actually a famous wizard name? Or a real name at all?

Comment: @VirtualValentin It's a famous wizard's name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wizard is:

> **Merlin**

Mix well

> There will be six letters that must be mixed. 1 tbsp = 3 tsp. Take the nth letter

The letters:

> Letters: NLIEMR

Unscrambles to:

> Merlin

Comment: I think its 3 tsp = 1 tbsp?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Fixed. Good catch.