# Who wrote this potion recipe? (#2)

Tags: word, cipher, literature

Below is a recipe for a Nosebleed Antidote written by a mysterious wizard. Just like other wizards before him [have done](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95331/who-wrote-this-potion-recipe), the one who wrote this recipe has hidden his name within the recipe. Can you find the name of this potion's author?

[image: recipe]

Hint: The author is a character from Harry Potter.

Comment: You should hide hints using the spoiler block

Comment: @melfnt Not necessarily if the hint is part of the puzzle rather than a later edit, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to do the following:

> Identify the ingredients (or, when tsp/tbsp are specified, single letters of ingredients) as in the previous puzzle. Here, "heat" is an ingredient. We get: T GOLD A L HEAT Y KOI O.

Then

> "stir" ingredients by moving them forward (clockwise) or backward (anticlockwise) in the alphabet by the number of steps given: R GOLD C L HEAT Y KOI R.

And then

> form an anagram, as before: **GILDEROY LOCKHART**.